# Why does stackoverflow and it's sister websites not use fluid layout?

Tags: support, user-interface, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can SO have a fluid vs. fixed-width layout?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout)

I am just sitting in my free time and going through StackOverflow's design. One of the things I am wondering is, why did the designers of stackoverflow not use fluid layout for this? I am viewing it on my 1920 * 1080 screen and I see only only my middle screen fills up the content.  The left and right sections are completely empty. It is using a standard 960px header and content width. My question is, why did they not create a fluid layout. Is there any disadvantage to it?

Comment: One thing is a huge block of text that spans across the *entire* screen is **really hard** to read.

Comment: Another thing is that you don't need to keep your browser window maximised at all times.