# Is there a setting I can change to optimize SO for my widescreen monitor?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I have a 24" monitor that I run at 1920x1080 resolution.  When I view SO there is an excessive amount of whitespace.  And the code 'example' markup boxes often truncate the data (they provide scrollbars).

Is there a way I can allow for more browser screen usage on SO?

With a monitor and resolution of my choosing it'd be beneficial for me not to have to scroll in a webpage to see content.  Specifically the code snippet markup area's.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Stack Exchange sites use a maximum width, and requests to change that have been declined.

Comment: ...as you can see: [Can SO have a fluid vs. fixed-width layout?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout)

Comment: I'm sure you could make a user-script to do it, just to see how crappy it would look.

Comment: @AlEverett - Bummer, literally 2/3rd of my window is not being used.  I believe usability is important too in regards to the code snippet scrolling as well (that is my main desire/request)

Comment: Well, you *could* switch it to the Mobile view (link in the footer) which will fill up the whole screen viewport.

Comment: Ctrl + MouseWheel ?

Comment: Look at this big garage. I need a bigger car.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins - Look at this big garage, weird I still can't open my car doors.  ;)

Comment: I often wonder why people seem to only use maximized windows...

Comment: @AndrewBarber: It makes us feel bigger, so hopefully the bears won't attack us.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Even with the non-maximized window the code snippet markup area still has scrollbars.  With a monitor and resolution of my choosing it'd be beneficial for me not to have to scroll in a webpage to see content.

Comment: There must be a way of injecting a custom CSS file into a website. If that was possible, it'd be easy.

Comment: It should be possible using GreaseMonkey.

Answer (score 3):

You could use two browser windows, and put them side-by-side to read more than one question at a time :)

Comment: I'm not sure if joking, or genius...anyway, the SE layout is too wide for a 1920 screen...at least for mine.

Comment: Well, it *was* an off-the-cuff answer. But I noticed on a 1600x900 display that even though part of the page is chopped off, I can still read all of the Q/A text when 2 Chrome windows are side-by-side. So this actually works for me...

Comment: If I overlap half the sidebar, I can have 3 SO windows side-by-side. Oh, 2560 monitors...

Comment: @Kevin - Mmm... very nice :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what the problem is here. For me I run SE sites in a chrome window that is just the right size, and for other sites I use different sized windows.

But then I don't run anything fullscreen - I'd prefer to not waste the space by extending something that doesn't need it, and SE doesn't need to be any wider.

Comment: Can you take a screencap of how it looks for you?