# Why so much whitespace?

Tags: feature-request, design

Stack Overflow is very useful, and much of that comes from the code samples.

Yet again, I am having to scroll to the right to see all of the code in an answer I am looking at, while at the same there is a huge amount of whitespace at the left and right of my screen on a desktop.

Could the layout not take this into consideration and allow the code window more space?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5070/180276