# Revisit: Format the site content according to the window width

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

The Stack Exchange website is a annoying to view at anything but the Stack Exchange Official Window Width. (Which is [about to change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites).) Use a narrow window, and you get truncated text. Use a wide window and you get a lot of blank space. (Except for a few moderator tools which are exclusively available from the otherwise blank left margin and are not visible at all unless you make your window wider than the SEOWW!)

Please let us get a comfortable experience at *our* choice of window width, chosen to suit our monitor setup, eyesight and window placement habits. Browser window size affects *every site you use*, so "fixing" it for SE can just break something else.  **The window width is a user choice, not a site choice.**

[Can SO have a fluid vs. fixed-width layout?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout) was declined, apparently on the basis that if you have a wider window than the SEOWW, it's not too bad. But for those of us who have a preferred window width narrower than the SEOWW, it's much worse: there's some stuff we have to keep scrolling horizontally for, and even stuff that we **cannot access at all**.  A lot has changed since that request was made in 2009 and declined in 2013, and it's time to revisit this issue.

Comment: Isn't that already what [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout?rq=1) was asking for? And it was declined.

Comment: I have, in the past, used https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Wide to achieve this with workable but not awesome results.

Comment: The request was declined in May 2013, but a lot has changed since then in both the SE site design and the user stories it needs to support, so we should reconsider it in 2016.  For example, the moderator tool Gilles refers to didn't even exist in 2013.

Comment: @NicolBolas More or less. Though the discussion at the time centered around doing something useful for people with wider windows; my concern here is people with narrower windows, for which the UX is worse.

Comment: +1. Web sites should work with ~portrait aspect-ratio windows. Anything that imposes wider than that is self-centered, not user-friendly, and likely not accessibility-friendly.

Comment: The width does not need to be fluid to at least partially solve the issue, if fluid width is too much work. Just having one or two alternative widths that get selected based on viewport size would be useful if that is easier to implement.